# Importing models from another maya project

Tags: maya

I created a scene in Maya in which I created my enviroment (flour, walls etc). In another scene I designed my character and I hooked up it's rig. Now I am looking for a way to export my character from one scene and import him in to another one.

I did a google search and all I could find was exporting for blender, exporting for unity and such.

Is there an easy way to do this without losing any information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**File → Import** will load other scenes into current scene. **File → Export** allows you to conditionally export things from scenes.

**PS**: Yes its as obvious as that. But depends on your rig whether it will work (it usually does that's what the namespace is for). Maya does not enforce sanity.

Comment: I suppose this was a very noobish question that is the reason it got downvoted but I just started Maya and I want to be sure for my each move without losing anything. Thank you friend

Comment: @JohnDemetriou I didnt downvote, its just that the answer is in your question. So yes it shows off inability for own initiative. The way you ensure that you do not loose things is to test the process and backup your progress (turn incremental save on and/or use version control). Nothing in maya guarantees lossfree transfer. Anyway welcome to gd.se even tough maya questions are a bit offtopic here.

Comment: Well yeah. I didn't think of applying incremental save. Thanks. I will do that from now on to keep backups